# Natvis визуализация для динамического массива\ хеш-таблицы

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка, визуализация

В образовательных целях делаю свою реализацию хеш-таблицы с открытым хешированием на основе своего односвязного списка. Хочу сделать для нее адекватную визуализацию при отладке с помощью Natvis. Визуализация для списков успешно получилась.

Например в unordered_map или new int[100] при отладке отображаются все индексы в которых есть данные. Нужен хотя бы пример Natvis файла для динамического массива по типу int* arr[100].
Реализацию natvis для unordered_map видел но такая не подходит.
Не совсем разобрался как работать с указателями в Natvis. В базовом представлении, т.е. по умолчанию отображается только начало хеш-таблицы, т.е. первый список,

Нужна подобная визуализация:

```
Имя         Значение        Тип
P           0x0159dc10{10}  int*
P[0]        10              int
P[5]        2               int
```

Так как хеш-таблица имеет указатель на массив то думаю с примером для int* arr[] смогу дальше разобраться.

```
  Ant_List<int>* table = new Ant_List<int>[100];
```

Если вдруг то Natvis для односвязного списка получилась такой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="Ant_List&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{size = {count}}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]">count</Item>
      <LinkedListItems>
        <Size>count</Size>
        <HeadPointer>first</HeadPointer>
        <NextPointer>Next</NextPointer>
        <ValueNode>Data</ValueNode>
      </LinkedListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natvis:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="simList">
    <DisplayString>{{ size={count}}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]">count</Item>
      <Item Name="[count_bucket]">count_bucket</Item>
      <CustomListItems MaxItemsPerView="5000">
        <Variable Name="i" InitialValue="0" />
        <Size>count_bucket</Size>
        <Loop>
          <Item Name="{i}" Condition="list[i].count > 0">list[i]</Item> 
          <Exec>i++</Exec>
        </Loop>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Вставляю 2 элемента в хеш-таблицу

```
 simList l;
    l.add(10, 20);//(key,value)
    l.add(0, 15);
    l.add(0, 9);
```

Получаю

```
Имя             Значение        
l               {size=3}
[size]          3
[count_bucket]  2        
[0]             {size=2}
[10]            {size=1}
```

Надеюсь кому-нибудь да поможет.